# jQuery lightBox plugin for gallery with thumbnails and a main image

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Basically I have a image gallery with thumbnails and a "main" image - so clicking on a thumbnail image updates the main image with the related full size image.

Thumbnail Image:

```
<a href="/images/<?php echo $product->image; ?>" onclick="$('#main-image').attr('src', '/images/<?php echo $product->image; ?>'; $('#main-image-link').attr('href', this.href); return false;">
    <img src="/images/<?php echo $product->image; ?>" alt="" />
</a>
```

Main Image:

```
<a id="main-image-link" href="/images/<?php echo $product->image; ?>" class="lightbox">
    <img src="/images/<?php echo $product->image ?>" alt="" id="main-image" />
</a>
```

And here is the lightbox code:

```
$(function() {
     $('a.lightbox').lightBox(); 
});
```

http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

So as you can see, the lightbox is activated upon clicking the main image. the problem I am having is that clicking on the main image only brings up a lightbox for that image only.

What I would like is for it to show a lightbox that displays all images (with the lightbox for the currently selected main image as the starting point).

Answer (score 0):

The LightBox plugin does this automatically.

```
<a class="lightbox" href="image1.jpg"><img src="image1thumb.jpg" /></a>
<a class="lightbox" href="image2.jpg"><img src="image2thumb.jpg" /></a>
<a class="lightbox" href="image3.jpg"><img src="image3thumb.jpg" /></a>
```

Then...

```
$('A.lightbox').lightBox();
```

If you don't want to put the links/images on the page, just use the CSS `display: none`.

Comment: No, the 'links' are in fact thumbnails. Clicking on a thumbnail displays a larger version of the image (on the page) - clicking on the larger version opens up a lightbox with an even larger version of the image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get the gallery working, just like they have on the [Example page](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) (create an unordered list, which will make sure next-previous navigation is working).

```
$(function() {
    $('#gallery a').lightBox({fixedNavigation:true});
});
```

And only THEN you add the logic of refreshing your main image, since it's something custom that you're doing on top of plugin's basic functionality.

Comment: The gallery is working if I set the thumbnail image classes to "lightbox" - however this means that the lightbox appears upon clicking a thumbnail - this is not the desired action, as I have explained in my original post.

Comment: The last sentence of your question in unclear: "create a lightbox gallery for all the images"? Please consider rephrasing and clarifying the current and desired use cases.